# Create a list of Map from csv feeder in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I am using Gatling pebble template in my Gatling simulation, this works with a `Map` like this

```scala
val mapValuesFeeder = Iterator.continually(Map("mapValues" -> List(
    Map("id" -> "1", "weight" -> "10"),
    Map("id" -> "2", "weight" -> "20"),
)))
```

but I don't want to hardcode these values in a `Map`, how can I create a map similar to above `Map` from CSV feeder data?

Comment: Did you have a look to https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/session/feeder/#csv-feeders?

Comment: yes i tried this: <val records: Seq[Map[String, Any]] = csv("myFile.csv").readRecords > and i am then getting this data to a list of map  like : val feeddata= Iterator.continually(Map("mapValues" -> List(records) , this does not give me compile error but does not work.

Comment: Why not use a classical feeder and directly use the varaibles ${id} and ${weight} in your scenario ?

Comment: Actually i am using Pebble template , where my input json changes with number of values in map , tried with simple feeder does not work.